# Setting orthographic view in Gazebo world file

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to define not only the camera position in the world file, but also if it the view of the camera should be **orthographic** or **perspective**? By default it seems to be perspective.

This relates to: https://answers.ros.org/question/11178/initial-view-after-gazebo-starts/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380684/setting-orthographic-view-in-gazebo-world-file/) by [flood](https://answers.ros.org/users/54873/flood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question: Yes!

```
<gui>
  <camera name="user_camera">
    <projection_type>orthographic</projection_type>
    <pose>1.5 -1.25 0 0 1.578 0</pose>
  </camera>
</gui>
```

For more information: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.8&elem=world

---

Originally posted by [flood](https://answers.ros.org/users/54873/flood/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0